# use sqlite check to validate whether date with proper format is entered in the column

Tags: sqlite, date, constraints

I have created a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE case_status(data_entry_timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')) NOT NULL,
                         case_number TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                         case_name TEXT DEFAULT MISSING, 
                         death_reportdate DATE CONSTRAINT death_reportdate_chk CHECK (death_reportdate==strftime('%Y-%m-%d',death_reportdate)),
                         );
```

The column `death_reportdate` need to have a date with pre-defined format (e.g. 2000-12-31). I created the table, inserted some rows of data, and then try to modified data in `death_reportdate`, the check rule seems to be bypassed when I enter some random string to it.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Create table query you presented obviously contains syntax error; if problem persists, please submit actual create query you use, and test if you still have problem with it. Also, you might have check constraint disabled; verify it by executing `pragma ignore_check_constraints;` - 1 means your checks disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You had an extra comma at the end.  Correct code:

```
CREATE TABLE case_status(data_entry_timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')) NOT NULL,
    case_number TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    case_name TEXT DEFAULT MISSING, 
    death_reportdate DATE CONSTRAINT death_reportdate_chk CHECK (death_reportdate==strftime('%Y-%m-%d',death_reportdate))
    )
```

Comment: I tried using the same strftime for date constraint. But it is accepting any string with 2 hyphens

Comment: Not sure why this has 4 votes, it doesn't work. `INSERT INTO case_status (case_number, death_reportdate) VALUES ('123', 'a');` should be failing because 'a' is not a properly formatted date. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775669/1858327).

Answer (score 4):

it is an old Topic but i had the the same Problem. if the strftime method Fails to Format the string( a bad Input) it retuns null, so you have to check is not null in the end

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution which works like a charm:

```
`date` DATE CHECK(date IS strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date))
```

This also works with the `time`:

```
`time` TIME CHECK(time IS strftime('%H:%M:%S', time))
```

Use this to define your column. I think that is a more elegant solution than checking for `null` value.

Comment: This solution allows `NULL` to be stored in the `CHECK`ed columns.

Answer (score 4):

First, two small notes.

1. I'm using the `TEXT` type since SQLite does not have "real types." [It has 5 column "affinities"](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), `INTEGER`, `TEXT`, `BLOB`, `REAL`, and `NUMERIC`. If you say `DATE` then it uses `NUMERIC` which can behave a little weirdly in my opinion. I find it best to explicitly use one of the 5 affinities.
2. I'm using `date(...)` instead of `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)` because [they are the same thing](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#overview).

Let's break down why the original question did not work.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP.example;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE example (
    deathdate TEXT CHECK (deathdate == date(deathdate))
);
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES ('2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM TEMP.example;
```

Running this lets all three values get into the database. Why? Let's check the documentation for [`CHECK` constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#check_constraints).

> If the result is zero (integer value 0 or real value 0.0), then a constraint violation has occurred. If the CHECK expression evaluates to NULL, or any other non-zero value, it is not a constraint violation.

If you run `SELECT 'a' == date('a');` you'll see it is `NULL`. Why? Check `SELECT date('a');` and you'll see it is also `NULL`. Huh, maybe the [documentation for `==`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators) can help?

> Note that there are two variations of the equals and not equals operators. Equals can be either = or ==. [...]
>
> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL.

We need to use `IS`, not `==`, and trying that we see that `'a'` no longer gets in.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP.example;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE example (
    deathdate TEXT CHECK (deathdate IS date(deathdate))
);
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES ('2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO TEMP.example (deathdate) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM TEMP.example;
```

If you don't want `NULL` to get in, simple change it to `deathdate TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (deathdate IS date(deathdate))`